# Extract first element of list of list of list of list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list of list of list of list, who's 3rd element looks like this:

```
[
[[-0.8690725419806353, -0.08389000630791843, 0.7791382771921971, -0.21049789958222198], [-0.7007253732065291, 0.99458521937916, -0.5468526445976842, -0.3094246565483987]],

[[0.584256147560986, -0.5642927958007717, 0.21759356280359254, -0.06807820714092316], [-0.9779032680122586, 0.24546752298204022, 0.3751715219217411, -0.3146135836256405]],

[[-0.5398355639736792, 0.4502589522424809, 0.9293381308257145, -0.10657822991597832], [-0.6113730000884487, 0.9140987217023038, 0.251920069381135, 0.42646522786278185]],

[[-0.23324198103994065, 0.09276611770008003, -0.5799583815644322, 0.23100380680142574], [-0.679057196855118, -0.7221510084412031, 0.5840055827718216, 0.1973048386398748]],

[[0.43867699536415694, 0.27146397192191607, 0.7011538998707785, 0.8932145525910065], [0.09131111620483745, -0.14453114049637228, 0.6039831172025221, 0.7754730090802249]],

[[0.6802994135674767, -0.2327763818549724, -0.3282557058999114, -0.2724537918871204], [0.7147975426033915, -0.9615052173793399, -0.3368913254473691, -0.4013739657188222]]
]
```

The data above is the 3rd element of a list, I would like to extract the first element of every list inside this 3rd element, so at the end I would get something like this

```
list1 = [ -0.8690725419806353,0.584256147560986,-0.5398355639736792,-0.23324198103994065,0.43867699536415694,0.6802994135674767]

list2 = [ -0.08389000630791843,-0.5642927958007717,0.4502589522424809,0.09276611770008003,0.27146397192191607,-0.2327763818549724]
```

... and so on

How to extract this data from my data structure? (note that this data above is already the 3rd element in the main root list so it needs to be extracted from that too as it's [3] element)

Comment: Something like `lists = [inner[0] for inner in main[3]]`?

Comment: The 3rd element is kind of confusing the question. It's not relevant since you can just do `arr = main[3]`... Then do whatever with the resulting `arr`. I'm guessing what you want is `flat_arr = [[x for xs in xss for x in xs] for xss in arr]` then `transpose = list(zip(*flat_arr))`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes that can be done to save it in a variable and then work with that variable

Comment: Do you know how indexing in lists work? if you do, what's the exact problem? You just have to use the correct indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [
    [[-0.8690725419806353, -0.08389000630791843, 0.7791382771921971, -0.21049789958222198], [-0.7007253732065291, 0.99458521937916, -0.5468526445976842, -0.3094246565483987]],
    [[0.584256147560986, -0.5642927958007717, 0.21759356280359254, -0.06807820714092316], [-0.9779032680122586, 0.24546752298204022, 0.3751715219217411, -0.3146135836256405]],
    [[-0.5398355639736792, 0.4502589522424809, 0.9293381308257145, -0.10657822991597832], [-0.6113730000884487, 0.9140987217023038, 0.251920069381135, 0.42646522786278185]],
    [[-0.23324198103994065, 0.09276611770008003, -0.5799583815644322, 0.23100380680142574], [-0.679057196855118, -0.7221510084412031, 0.5840055827718216, 0.1973048386398748]],
    [[0.43867699536415694, 0.27146397192191607, 0.7011538998707785, 0.8932145525910065], [0.09131111620483745, -0.14453114049637228, 0.6039831172025221, 0.7754730090802249]],
    [[0.6802994135674767, -0.2327763818549724, -0.3282557058999114, -0.2724537918871204], [0.7147975426033915, -0.9615052173793399, -0.3368913254473691, -0.4013739657188222]]
    ]

flat = [xss[0] for xss in arr]
transpose = list(zip(*flat))
```

Results in:

```
[(-0.8690725419806353,
  0.584256147560986,
  -0.5398355639736792,
  -0.23324198103994065,
  0.43867699536415694,
  0.6802994135674767),
 (-0.08389000630791843,
  -0.5642927958007717,
  0.4502589522424809,
  0.09276611770008003,
  0.27146397192191607,
  -0.2327763818549724),
 (0.7791382771921971,
  0.21759356280359254,
  0.9293381308257145,
  -0.5799583815644322,
  0.7011538998707785,
  -0.3282557058999114),
 (-0.21049789958222198,
  -0.06807820714092316,
  -0.10657822991597832,
  0.23100380680142574,
  0.8932145525910065,
  -0.2724537918871204)]
```

Comment: Seems to work fine, it's short and simple, and each sublist can be accessed with their respective index.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
main = [
[[-0.8690725419806353, -0.08389000630791843, 0.7791382771921971, 
-0.21049789958222198], [-0.7007253732065291, 0.99458521937916, -0.5468526445976842, 
-0.3094246565483987]],

[[0.584256147560986, -0.5642927958007717, 0.21759356280359254, -0.06807820714092316], 
[-0.9779032680122586, 0.24546752298204022, 0.3751715219217411, -0.3146135836256405]],

[[-0.5398355639736792, 0.4502589522424809, 0.9293381308257145, -0.10657822991597832], 
[-0.6113730000884487, 0.9140987217023038, 0.251920069381135, 0.42646522786278185]],

[[-0.23324198103994065, 0.09276611770008003, -0.5799583815644322, 
0.23100380680142574], [-0.679057196855118, -0.7221510084412031, 0.5840055827718216, 
0.1973048386398748]],

[[0.43867699536415694, 0.27146397192191607, 0.7011538998707785, 0.8932145525910065], 
[0.09131111620483745, -0.14453114049637228, 0.6039831172025221, 0.7754730090802249]],

[[0.6802994135674767, -0.2327763818549724, -0.3282557058999114, -0.2724537918871204], 
[0.7147975426033915, -0.9615052173793399, -0.3368913254473691, -0.4013739657188222]]
]

ListNo = 1
index = 0

while (len(main[0][0]) > index):
    lists = []
    for l in main:
        lists.append(l[0][index]) 
    index += 1
    print("List "+str(ListNo)+ ": ",lists)
    ListNo += 1

index = 0
while (len(main[0][1]) > index):
    lists1 = []
    for l in main:
        lists1.append(l[1][index]) 
    index += 1
    print("List "+str(ListNo)+ ": ",lists1)
    ListNo += 1
```

Output:

```
List 1:  [-0.8690725419806353, 0.584256147560986, -0.5398355639736792, 
-0.23324198103994065, 0.43867699536415694, 0.6802994135674767]
List 2:  [-0.08389000630791843, -0.5642927958007717, 0.4502589522424809, 
0.09276611770008003, 0.27146397192191607, -0.2327763818549724]
List 3:  [0.7791382771921971, 0.21759356280359254, 0.9293381308257145, 
-0.5799583815644322, 0.7011538998707785, -0.3282557058999114]
List 4:  [-0.21049789958222198, -0.06807820714092316, -0.10657822991597832, 
0.23100380680142574, 0.8932145525910065, -0.2724537918871204]
List 5:  [-0.7007253732065291, -0.9779032680122586, -0.6113730000884487, 
-0.679057196855118, 0.09131111620483745, 0.7147975426033915]
List 6:  [0.99458521937916, 0.24546752298204022, 0.9140987217023038, 
-0.7221510084412031, -0.14453114049637228, -0.9615052173793399]
List 7:  [-0.5468526445976842, 0.3751715219217411, 0.251920069381135, 
0.5840055827718216, 0.6039831172025221, -0.3368913254473691]
List 8:  [-0.3094246565483987, -0.3146135836256405, 0.42646522786278185, 
0.1973048386398748, 0.7754730090802249, -0.4013739657188222]
```